# Probem with Delegate method not executing

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I'm newer to swift and learning about the Delegate communication pattern to pass data between controllers. I'm trying to keep it simple and just want to change the background color and the text of a label.

I was able to set a protocol in my main view controller.

```
protocol MyViewControllerlDelegate: AnyObject {
    func changeLabelName (title: String)
    func changeBackgroundColor (color: UIColor)
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var viewControllerDelegate: MyViewControllerlDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func toNextView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        viewControllerDelegate?.changeLabelName(title: "HELLO THERE")
        viewControllerDelegate?.changeBackgroundColor(color: .systemCyan)
        
        let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController
        present(secondVC, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

In my second View controller I conform to the MyViewControllerDelegate and set the delegate.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, MyViewControllerlDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
    var myTitle: String?
    var myMainView = MyViewController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        myMainView.viewControllerDelegate = self
        
    }
    
    func changeLabelName(title: String) {
        myLabel.text = title
    }
    
    func changeBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }

}
```

Whenever my second controller is shown the view is white and my label stays the same. I've tried following a few tutorials online and looking at similar problems on here, but I can't figure out why my Delegate methods are not executing on my second view controller.

I've noticed that if I call the methods in the `viewDidLoad` it works. Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Comment: cn u check ```viewControllerDelegate```  is ```nil``` or not inside ```toNextView```?

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of the delegate pattern. Your code is trying to pass data forward, not backward. Since `MyViewController` is directly creating and displaying `SecondViewController`, `MyViewController` can give the data directly to the new `SecondViewController` instance. No delegate required.

Comment: Wrong implementation of protocol. You need to learn first how to work protocol check this link (https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working because you create an `object` of a `class` while doing it `viewDidLoad` will be called.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, MyViewControllerlDelegate {
    ........
    var myMainView = MyViewController()
    ........
}
```

This is not appropriate use of `delegate` [@HangarRash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20287183/hangarrash) mentioned in comment.

need to pass data simply in forward data passing scenario. because delegates work in backward data passing.

you can do it like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func toNextView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.viewBgColor = .systemCyan
        secondVC.titleText = "HELLO THERE"
        present(secondVC, animated: true)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
    var viewBgColor: UIColor?
    var titleText: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        changeLabelName(title: titleText) 
        changeBackgroundColor(color: viewBgColor)
    }
    
    func changeLabelName(title: String) {
        myLabel.text = title
    }
    
    func changeBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the response. I was also able to find a good article online that helped as well. The link is here: (https://medium.com/@icodespree/communication-patterns-in-swift-89442ff6af29)

Answer (score 1):

No need here for delegate pattern.
You are trying to pass data forward, not backward.
for that you do not need delegate
just pass the value to your "SecondViewController" functions

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func toNextView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.viewBackgroundColor = .systemCyan
        secondVC.labelNameText = "HELLO THERE"
        present(secondVC, animated: true)  
    }
    
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
    var viewBackgroundColor: UIColor?
    var labelNameText: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        changeLabelName(title: labelNameText) 
        changeBackgroundColor(color: viewBackgroundColor)  
    }
    
  private func changeLabelName(title: String?) {
        myLabel.text = title
    }
    
  private func changeBackgroundColor(color: UIColor?) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }

}
```